# Percentage of questions that are unanswered or answered

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stackexchange

I put together [this simple query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/revision/334044/431259/) which calculates the total percentage of answered questions and unanswered questions. The formulas used to calculate these are shown below:

$$
\text{Answered Percentage} = 100 - \left(\frac{\text{Unanswered}}{\text{Answered}} \times 100\right) \\
\text{Unanswered Percentage} = \frac{\text{Unanswered}}{\text{Answered}} \times 100
$$

Finally, here's the source:

```
DECLARE @TotalQuestions DECIMAL = (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts
);

DECLARE @UnansweredQuestions DECIMAL = (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts WHERE AnswerCount = 0
);

-- The percentage of un-answered questions. Calculated
-- using this:
  -- (Unanswered Questions / Total Site Questions) * 100
SELECT 
  (@UnansweredQuestions / @TotalQuestions) * 100.0
AS [Percentage Of Unanswered Questions];

-- The percentage of answered questions. Calculated
-- using this:
  -- 100 - ((Unanswered Questions / Total Site Questions) * 100)
SELECT
  100 - ((@UnansweredQuestions / @TotalQuestions) * 100.0)
AS [Perentage Of Answered Questions];
```

Comment: Any reason for not addressing questions that are in a non-responsive state (closed/on-hold)?

Comment: @Snowhawk04 No, not really. I didn't think of that until after I posted. I'll probably post another question once I have changed it and added improvements from answers.

Comment: @Quill Yup. I created this query specifically for Math.SE.

Comment: In your description you say `Unanswered Percentage = (Unanswered / Answered) * 100`.  I think you mean `Unanswered Percentage = (Unanswered / Total) * 100`, which would match your source.  (And similarly for the other formula in your description.)

Comment: I agree with @mathmandan.  These percentage calculations are wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Comments

Your comments are mostly clutter, and I mean that because your naming is good enough to where the comments are mostly irrelevant. Also, if you do need to make multi-line comment, you can use the same syntax in SQL as in pretty much everything else.

Look at this, the comments and the code read almost identically:

> ```
> /**
>  * The percentage of un-answered questions. Calculated
>  * using this:
>  * (Unanswered Questions / Total Site Questions) * 100
>  */
> SELECT 
>   (@UnansweredQuestions / @TotalQuestions) * 100.0 AS [Percentage Of Unanswered Questions];
> ```

There is an elegant way of assigning an alias in an expression that would make it even easier to read:

```
SELECT 
  [Percentage Of Unanswered Questions] = (@UnansweredQuestions / @TotalQuestions) * 100.0
```

Does exactly the same thing, but reads more like typical code, where you name a thing *before* assigning it something, rather than after.

---

#### Dead code

Your first `SELECT` query is never displayed. There are two ways you could fix that, either by making them two different columns, or two different rows (according to your needs).

[**Columns:**](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/334121)

```
SELECT 
  [Percentage Of Unanswered Questions] = (@UnansweredQuestions / @TotalQuestions) * 100.0
, [Perentage Of Answered Questions] = 100 - ((@UnansweredQuestions / @TotalQuestions) * 100.0);
```

[image: columns]

[**Rows:**](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/334127)

```
SELECT 
  [Type of value] = 'Percentage Of Unanswered Questions'
  , [Value] = (@UnansweredQuestions / @TotalQuestions) * 100.0
UNION
SELECT
  'Percentage Of Answered Questions'
  , 100 - ((@UnansweredQuestions / @TotalQuestions) * 100.0);
```

[image: rows]

Answer (score 5):

Your code is formatted well, and has good comments, but:

- `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts WHERE AnswerCount = 0`: as @Snowhawk04 pointed out, this also selects closed questions. `AND ClosedDate IS null` usually works.
- I don't see why you don't join the two `SELECT` statements into one `SELECT`.
- Your formula displayed in the question, you don't divide the `Unanswered Qs` by the `Answered Qs`, you divide `Unanswered Qs` by `Total Qs`.
- You don't *need* `AS` statements with or without them provides the same functionality, they're kinda cluttery.
- Rather than subtracting \$100\$ from the unanswered percentage, simply generate the `Answered Qs` by subtracting the `Unanswered Qs` from the `Total Qs` and use the same formula for `Unanswered Qs`, like so:  `((@TotalQuestions  - @UnansweredQuestions) / @TotalQuestions) * 100.0`

Comment: About your first point, semicolons should be used between each declaration. In every other DBMS you'd get a syntax error without them, Microsoft's SQL plays pretty loose with the syntax.